# Is there an equivalent to creating a C# implicit operator in F#?

Tags: c#, f#

In C# I can add implicit operators to a class as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int data;

    public static implicit operator MyClass(int i)
    {
        return new MyClass { data = i };
    }

    public static implicit operator MyClass(string s)
    {
        int result;

        if (int.TryParse(s, out result))
        {
            return new MyClass { data = result };
        }
        else
        {
            return new MyClass { data = 999 };
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return data.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then I can pass any function that is expecting a MyClass object a string or an int.
eg

```
public static string Get(MyClass c)
{
    return c.ToString();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s1 = Get(21);
    string s2 = Get("hello");
    string s3 = Get("23");
}
```

Is there a way of doing this in F#?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As others have pointed out, there is no way to do implicit conversion in F#.  However, you could always create your own operator to make it a bit easier to explicitly convert things (and to reuse any op_Implicit definitions that existing classes have defined):

```ml
let inline (!>) (x:^a) : ^b = ((^a or ^b) : (static member op_Implicit : ^a -> ^b) x)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```ml
type A() = class end
type B() = static member op_Implicit(a:A) = B()

let myfn (b : B) = "result"

(* apply the implicit conversion to an A using our operator, then call the function *)
myfn (!> A())
```

Comment: This appears to be an invalid prefix operator name in F# 2.0. Are the rules for operator names defined somewhere? I don't see anything on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx) page that indicates this restriction.

Comment: Omitting `~` from the name appears to work. Did the rules change?

Comment: @Daniel - yes, I think the rules must have changed.  Omitting the `~` won't quite work because it will make it an infix rather than prefix operator.  However, replacing `~` with `!` should work.

Comment: Can anybody explain what this first line `let implicit (!>) ...` does?

Comment: @robkuz it uses [Statically resolved type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) to essentially say: The !> operator can be used between two types a and b where there exists a op_Implicit defined on a or b that can do the conversion, and to use it as the definition of the function

Comment: great + helpful + outdated.

Answer (score 7):

Implicit conversion is rather problematic with respect to type safety and type inference, so the answer is: No, it actually would be a problematic feature.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.

Answer (score 3):

On a related note, it is possible to add implicit or explicit static members so C# can use them.

```
type Country =
| NotSpecified
| England
| Wales
| Scotland
| NorthernIreland
 with static member op_Implicit(c:Country) = 
   match c with | NotSpecified    -> 0
                | England         -> 1
                | Wales           -> 2
                | Scotland        -> 3
                | NorthernIreland -> 4
```

This allows a c# user to use `(int) Wales` for example

Answer (score 3):

As of F#6, there is now support for op_Implicit as long as the resolution is type-directed and clear e.g.

```ml
let x : System.Nullable<int> = 10 // valid in F#6

let doStuff (x:System.Nullable<int>) = ()
doStuff 10 // valid in F#6

type Foo() =
    static member X (x:System.Nullable<int>) = ()
Foo.X 10 // valid in F#6
```

Note that the first two example will give a warning (FS3391) which can be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the operator like this:

```
let casted = TargetClass.op_Implicit sourceObject
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @isaac-abraham and @kvb. I condensed their answers and built my typesafe ids, using implicit constructors that the op asked for:

```
type UserId =
  { id: string } // underlying, could be int or so as well
  static member op_Implicit(id:string) = { id = id }
  override r.ToString() = r.id

type ProductId =
  { id: string }
  static member op_Implicit(id:string) = { id = id }
  override r.ToString() = r.id

let id1 : UserId = "p1"
let id2 : UserId = "p1"
let id3 : UserId = "p2"
id1 = id2 // true
id1 = id3 // false
let pid1 : ProductId = "p1"
id1 = pid1 // type error, not comparable -> excellent, thats what this is for
```

Using records gives structural equality and even comparison works:

```
id3 > id1 // true
id3 < id1 // false
```