# Is there anyway to use C# implicit operators from F#?

Tags: c#, f#, implicit-conversion

If I have a C# class with implicit conversion to double, like so:

```cs
public class Parameter
{
    private double _value;
    public Parameter(double value) { _value = value }
    public static implicit operator double(Parameter p) { return _value; }
}
```

F# doesn't like me trying to use it as if it were a `float`:

```ml
let a = Parameter(4.0)
let b = Parameter(2.0)
let c = a * Math.Sin(b) <-- 'expected float, here Parameter'
```

Is there any way to do this (I'm guessing there isn't, based on [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1686895/11410)), and if not, what would be a decent workaround?

Comment: Thinks: I can add a `Value` property and use that everywhere, it's not beautiful, but less ugly that anything else I can think of...

Comment: Sadly not...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686895/is-there-an-equivalent-to-creating-a-c-sharp-implicit-operator-in-f

Answer (score 31, accepted):

F# does not perform implicit conversions, but it allows you to define an explicit operator to run them. See the [kvb's answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686895/is-there-an-equivalent-to-creating-a-c-sharp-implicit-operator-in-f):

```ml
let inline (!>) (x:^a) : ^b = ((^a or ^b) : (static member op_Implicit : ^a -> ^b) x)
```

This is using [statically resolved type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx) to say that either the input or the result needs to provide implicit conversion operator - these are compiled to methods named `op_Implicit`, so the F# compiler checks for a static method with this special name.

Using the `!>` operator, you can now explicitly say where you want to convert `Parameter` to a `float` (two times) in your code sample like this:

```ml
let a = Parameter(4.0) 
let b = Parameter(2.0) 
let c = !> a * Math.Sin(!> b)
```

I think the main reason for not allowing implicit conversions in F# is that it would make the type inference a bit more difficult and it would be hard for the compiler to give good error messages.

Comment: Hm, I can't decide which is uglier out of `A.Value * Math.Exp(time.Value) * Math.Sin(B.Value * time.Value)` and `!> A * Math.Exp(|> time) * Math.Sin(!> B * !> time)`

Comment: @Benjol I fully agree - In fact, I'm pretty convinced that using `!>` operator is uglier than using `.Value` property, so I would probably just use that. The `!>` operator is probably only useful if you need to write other generic functions.

Comment: What about if it is a C# generic, e.g.: `public static implicit operator MyClass<T>(T t) => ...`. The actual implementation is irrelevant. The code above does not work and it fails with: `The declared type parameter T cannot be used here since the type parameter cannot be resolved at compile time`.

Answer (score 1):

It won't let you do implicit conversions.  Make your conversions explicit where you need to.

See here for various ways to do it explicitly:
http://natehoellein.blogspot.com/2008/02/basic-type-conversions-with-f.html

Comment: Implicit operators aren't supported in general in F#. For instance the following doesn't compile: `let mutable a = 1.0 in a <- 2`.

Answer (score 1):

[FSharp.Interop.Dynamic](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic) uses the DLR, so for most people probably overkill, but has a function `Dyn.implicitConvert` for dynamically using the C# implicit operator.

```
   [<Test>] member basic.``Test Implicit Conversion`` ()=
                    let ele = 50
                    ele |> Dyn.implicitConvert |> should equal (decimal 50)
```