# How do I call Redis StringSet() from F#

Tags: f#, stackexchange.redis

I am using StackExchange.Redis to access a Redis instance.

I have the following working C# code:

```
public static void Demo()
{
    ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("xxx.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=xxx");

    IDatabase cache = connection.GetDatabase();

    cache.StringSet("key1", "value");
}
```

Here is the what I would hope would be the equivalent F# code:

```ml
let Demo() =
   let cx = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect @"xxx.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=xxx"
   let cache = cx.GetDatabase()
   cache.StringSet("key1", "value") |> ignore
```

However this does not compile - 'No overloads match for method StringSet'.  The StringSet method expects arguments of type RedisKey and RedisValue, and there seems to be some compiler magic going on in C# to convert the strings in the calling code into RedisKey and RedisValue.  The magic does not appear to exist in F#.  Is there a way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Are there `RedisKey.op_Implicit` and `RedisValue.op_Implicit` operators?

Comment: @Daniel - looks like it.  If I navigate to definition I get the following .fsi generated: 

type RedisKey =
...
   static member op_Implicit : key:string -> RedisKey
   static member op_Implicit : key:byte [] -> RedisKey
   static member op_Implicit : key:RedisKey -> byte []
   static member op_Implicit : key:RedisKey -> string

Comment: Then you'll need to do `StringSet(RedisKey.op_Implicit "key1", RedisValue.op_Implicit "value")`. Those are called automatically in C#, but not F#. You can also [define an "implicit" operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10720073/162396).

Comment: Awesome, looks like this will work.  If you post that as an answer I will mark it as such and get you magic interweb points.  Thanks!

Comment: I would personally extend string to have toRedisKey and toRedisVal funs. More readable, controllable, and clear what's going on. Do same for RedisKey to convert to string or whatever.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daniel, and thanks a lot Kit for asking

Answer (score 13):

Here is the working code, many thanks to @Daniel:

```ml
open StackExchange.Redis
open System.Collections.Generic

let inline (~~) (x:^a) : ^b = ((^a or ^b) : (static member op_Implicit: ^a -> ^b) x)

let Demo() =
   let cx = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect @"xxx.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password==xxx"
   let cache = cx.GetDatabase()

   // Setting a value - need to convert both arguments:
   cache.StringSet(~~"key1", ~~"value") |> ignore

   // Getting a value - need to convert argument and result:
   cache.StringGet(~~"key1") |> (~~) |> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: I have a similar problem
I have a string key and value
I want to put it into and get it out of redis

            let searchToken = RedisKey.op_Implicit ("myKey" + token)
            let resultValue = cache.StringGet(searchToken)
            let redisData = RedisValue.op_Implicit(resultValue)

When I run this, I get: The type 'RedisValue' does not support a conversion to the type ''a'

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  How do I tell the RedisValue.op_Implicit that it is indeed a string?