# F# seems to not leverage implicit .NET conversion operators

Tags: f#, implicit-conversion

According to

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-6.0#actionresultt-type
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asynchronous-action-1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0#operators

The following F# code should be legitimate:

```
[<HttpPost("post-data-2")>]
[<ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)>]
[<ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)>]
member this.PostData2(data: string): Task<ActionResult<int>> = 
    task {
        try 
            return this.Ok(0)
        with | x -> 
            return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, -1)
    }
```

Instead I get two compilation errors in the two 'return' lines

> Error FS0193  Type constraint mismatch. The type
> 'OkObjectResult'     is not compatible with type
> 'ActionResult'

and

> Error FS0193  Type constraint mismatch. The type
> 'ObjectResult'     is not compatible with type
> 'ActionResult'

This works however:

```
[<HttpPost("post-data-1")>]
[<ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)>]
[<ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)>]
member this.PostData1(data: string): Task<ActionResult<int>> = 
    task {
        try 
            return ActionResult<int>(this.Ok(0))
        with | x -> 
            return ActionResult<int>(this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, -1)) 
    }
```

**Why are the implicit cast operators not recognized by F#?**

Comment: F# tries its best to be a statically typed language, and `op_Implicit` kind of decreases predictable types. If you have type `a: 'T` and `b: 'U` you cannot do `a = b` and the like, or assign. With implicit operators, such *static, compile-time* guarantees would dwindle, and reasoning about code by just reading it becomes harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure there can be much of an answer besides "because the language designers decided for it to be that way". Implicit conversions are only used in a [narrow set of circumstances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/casting-and-conversions#net-style-implicit-conversions) in F#.

In addition to calling the constructor as you have, you should also be able to explicitly call `ActionResult.op_Implicit` or [define you own implicit conversion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10720073/14134059).