# Please explain this syntax

Tags: f#

From an [answer by kvb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688131/154766) about how to call implicit conversion operators:

```
let inline (!>) (x:^a) : ^b = ((^a or ^b) : (static member op_Implicit : ^a -> ^b) x)
```

I've known F# for a while but I just don't know how to parse the implementation here. What is `(^a or ^b)`? And the stuff after that? Please go over what each part represents grammatically.

Comment: bound to be a duplicate on SO somewhere - see the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dd548046.aspx

Comment: The docs explain constraints but not the function invocation seen here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`^a or ^b` means literally "`^a` or `^b`".

The colon `:` means "has" or "contained in", depending on how you look at it.

So the whole expression `(^a or ^b) : (static member op_Implicit : ^a -> ^b)` means "static member named "op_Implicit" that has type `^a -> ^b` and is defined on either type `^a` or type `^b`". This whole expression ultimately evaluates to a function of type `^a -> ^b`.

Then, the `x` placed to the right of that expression means "function application", just like in the usual F# syntax.

So the whole thing taken together would mean "on type `^a` or type `^b`, find a static member named "op_Implicit" that has type `^a -> ^b`, and apply that member to argument `x`".

For a bit more discussion of statically resolved constraints, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30305092/180286) or [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dd548046.aspx).